# How to display calculations, values and variables in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

For didactic purposes I like to perform and display calculations in Excel. To display calculations I use the following VBA worksheet-function:

```
Function DisplayFormula(range_rng As Range) As String
   Application.Volatile

   If range_rng.HasArray Then
        DisplayFormula = "<-- " & " {" & range_rng.FormulaArray & "}"    
   Else
        DisplayFormula = "<-- " & " " & range_rng.FormulaArray
   End If
End Function
```

This works, however, I'm stuck with the implementation of two modifications:

1. I would like to display the actual values that are called in range_rng.
2. I would like to display variables instead of the ranges. The variables would be assigned in a separate cell, next to the cell where they are called from (see graphic below).

Column "C" shows the (desired) output formats for DisplayFormula(B3):

[image: This is how the output should look like.]

Comment: use an array so arr() = range_rng.value2, then join this back up, to return a string out.

Comment: Using range_rng.value2 returns the output for range_rng (e.g. 12.5 above). I would like to return the calculation (e.g. =5/2+10 above). Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this brute force approach.
I can't say that this is optimized, but it can satisfy your two conditions above.

```
Function DisplayFormula2(r As Range, Optional o As Variant) As String
    Dim a, b, z, x, y, w
    Dim f As String, tf As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    If IsMissing(o) Then o = 0

    a = Array("+", "-", "/", "*", "%", "&", "^", "=", _
        "<", ">", "<=", ">=", "<>", "(", ")")

    f = r.FormulaArray: tf = f
    For Each b In a
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            tf = .Substitute(tf, b, "|")
        End With
    Next

    z = VBA.Split(tf, "|")

    For Each w In z
        Debug.Print w
        On Error Resume Next
        Set c = Range(w)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            If IsArray(x) Then
                ReDim Preserve x(UBound(x) + 1): x(UBound(x)) = w
                ReDim Preserve y(UBound(y) + 1): y(UBound(y)) = c.Offset(0, o).Value2
            Else
                x = Array(w)
                y = Array(c.Offset(0, o).Value2)
            End If
        End If
        Set c = Nothing
    Next

    If IsArray(x) Then
        For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
            With Application.WorksheetFunction
                f = .Substitute(f, x(i), y(i))
            End With
        Next
    End If
    DisplayFormula2 = IIf(r.HasArray, "<-- {" & f & "}", "<-- " & f)
End Function
```

By the way, I don't think you need to use `.Volatile` so I removed it.
It will recalculate as long as you set Calculation mode to Automatic.

**Actual Formula in C3:C5:**
C3: `=DisplayFormula(B3)`
C4: `=DisplayFormula2(B4)`
C5: `=DisplayFormula2(B5,-1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by changing the target cell to TEXT format. Try this:

```
Function DisplayFormula(range_rng As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"

    If range_rng.HasArray Then
        DisplayFormula = "<-- " & " {" & range_rng.FormulaArray & "}"
    Else
        DisplayFormula = "<-- " & " " & range_rng.FormulaArray
    End If
End Function
```